# Adding user-data-dir option to ChromeDriver makes it not work and timeout only

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

Using .NET's C#:

I was thrilled to learn how to start a web driver session with your local cookie data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27679811/1219280).

The browser now starts with my bookmarks and cookies loaded (I tested accessing sites that require authorization, to which I have already logged in in the past and saved the credentials).

However, for some reason, my web driver instance will not respond to a simple `GoToUrl()`. In fact, the command prompt is always reporting about the session timing out after 60 seconds.

What is interesting, **nevertheless**, is that the following **code will work if I simply suppress the line that adds the cookie path argument**. (I have done lots of stuff with ChromeDrive already).

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArgument(string.Format("user-data-dir={0}", "C:/Users/Me/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data"));

    IWebDriver wd = new ChromeDriver(options);

    wd.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

I tried other ChromeDriver overloads, such as the one that uses a ChromeDriverService, to no avail.

My chromedriver.exe obviously exists in D:/ (otherwise I would get a different error message).

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After further research, come across the following links:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/886

https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=962

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

Although I did not see any definitive conclusion, someone hinted that the problem occurs when there is another chrome instance already open.
I then made sure this does not happen - and now my webdriver instance opens with the desired profile and **works**.

As far as I understand, seems this is the expected behavior - you cannot have two instances running the very same profile. You may ask, then, how come I can run multiple web driver instances with no problem ? Well, this happens because instantiating a webdriver object - without specifying a specific profile - creates a temporary one. So all instances one opens run on different profiles.

Comment: Hello.. I have the same exact issue as you mentioned. I need to run multiple web driver instances with same shared session. I didn't quite get what you said in the last line about different profiles.. can you please explain?

Comment: You cannot have 2 instances running the **same profile**. But if you try to run multiple instances of web drivers, without specifying a profile, will work. Why ? Because when you do not specify one, a temporary (and apparently unique) one is created, and therefore no 2 instances are asked to run with the same profile - therefore you have no exception in the case of running multiple instances without specifying a profile.

Comment: Okk.. but that's not an option for me.. if I don't specify one, the temporary profile that's created doesn't share the session. That's my main constraint. I need 10 webdriver instances to run with same authentication as the client's IDP doesnt allow multiple simultaneous logins. As soon as one is created, other one logs out.

Comment: Well, my problem - and which my answer tried to explain - was that I was not succeeding in simply running a web browser with a profile. Loading the profile worked, but the web driver would not navigate anywhere. I then figured out that it was because I was firing several instances of web driver and trying to have all of them load the same profile. Doing it with a single instance only **works for running a web driver instance that loads a chrome profile**, which was the problem I was trying to solve.

Comment: You are seeking how to run multiple web driver instances with the same profile. I have not tried to solve that.